# COUNTIFS with different date formats in google sheets

Tags: date, google-sheets, countif

I have two spreadsheets:
(1) Contains an array of dates in this format: 22.08.2016 13:30
(2) Contains an array of ongoing month dates in this format: 08.2016

What I want to do is use "COUNTIF" to count all rows in spreadsheet (1) that match the month in spreadsheet (2).

My approach: `=COUNTIF(MONTH('spreadsheet1'!H1:H); "=MONTH('spreadsheet2'!D3)")` only returns "0".
Can you advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `counta + filter`:

`=COUNT(IFERROR(FILTER(A:A,MONTH(A:A)=MONTH(B1)),""))`

[image]

This formula may work too:

`=ArrayFormula(SUM(if(MONTH(A:A)=MONTH(B1),1,0)))`

Or even a bit harder, but this arrayformula will expand automatically, no need to drag down:

```
=QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(ArrayFormula(if(MONTH(A:A)=TRANSPOSE(MONTH(FILTER(B:B,B:B<>""))),1,0)),"select sum(Col"&JOIN("), sum(Col",ARRAYFORMULA(row(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COUNTA(B:B)))))&")",0)),"select Col2",0)
```

Comment: This works! I have also added a statement, so it works throughout more than one year

'=COUNTA(FILTER('spreadsheet1'!H1:H; MONTH('spreadsheet1'!H1:H)=MONTH(D3); YEAR('spreadsheet1'!H1:H)=YEAR(D3)))'

Comment: For some reason, when the Formula does not find anything, it always returns "1" instead of "0". Is there any fix for that?

Comment: That's because `counta` counts everything, even errors. It's better to use `count + iferror`, see the updated answer.